# JAX-WS context listener initializing failed in JBOSS

Tags: servlets, jax-ws, servletcontextlistener, initializing

I'm getting below error when trying to deploy a JAX-WS web service in JBOSS 4.0.3. I'm using JAX-WS RI runtime libraries. I'm not using JBOSS-WS the JBOSS specific JAX-WS.

```
18:31:21,125 INFO  [STDOUT] Feb 20, 2015 6:31:21 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
18:31:21,203 INFO  [STDOUT] Feb 20, 2015 6:31:21 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor:   
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.newTransformerFactory(XmlUtil.java:392)
at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.newTransformerFactory(XmlUtil.java:400)
at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.<clinit>(XmlUtil.java:233)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory.getXMLInputFactory(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:127)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory.<clinit>(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:176)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3669)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)...
```

In the `web.xml` I've put the listener for the class:       `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener`

Comment: Hm, I came across the same problem.... with JAX-WS-RT ... but under Glassfish 4.1 / JDK 1.7. Got this after adding JAX-WS to classpath because of another ClassNotFoundException :-(
 
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: Laufzeitdeskriptor konnte nicht geparst werden: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)

Answer (score 1):

The class `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` is abstract, and you need an Implementation of that class somewhere in your classpath. The exception `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)` often indicates a version conflict in your dependencies, because the implementation you use was build against a different version of the interface.

To solve it you must use a matching implementation. TransformerFactory-implementations are contained withing XML parsers like Xalan or Xerces. You can tell Java to use a certain parser implementation by setting the appropriate system properties:

```
    Properties p = System.getProperties();
    p.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    p.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
    p.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");
    System.setProperties(p);
```

Executing this during initialization of your application will set the default parser implementation to the internal Xalan parser of the JRE. To use other parsers, include their dependencies and put the Implementations classes' names in the setProperties methods.